# Will a UIBarButton's target create a retain cycle?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm trying to isolate the cause of a retain cycle, and found this suspicious. It's a useful pattern for me, but will this code create a retain cycle?

```
myVC: UIViewController {
  private lazy var cancelButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
    return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(onTapCancel))
  }()
}
```

I can't tell if the API will retain that reference to `self` in a weak or strong way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the target-action mechanism Apple uses does not typically allow controls to retain their targets for this reason, although it's a little difficult to find a solid reference.

If you check [the documentation for `UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:), you'll see:

> The control does not retain the object in the *target* parameter. It is your responsibility to maintain a strong reference to the target object while it is attached to a control.

If you check [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html), you'll see:

> Control objects do not (and should not) retain their targets. However, clients of controls sending action messages (applications, usually) are responsible for ensuring that their targets are available to receive action messages.